# parametrized generic type for Serilog.ForContext()

Tags: c#, .net, generics

i have a bunch of records that look like

```
internal record Carrier : MavApiRecordBase{
    /// <summary>
    /// Identificativo Carrier
    /// </summary>
    [JsonPropertyName("id")]
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Tag (nome) del Carrier
    /// </summary>
    [JsonPropertyName("tag")]
    public string Name { get => Name; set => Name = validateString<Carrier>(value, 64); }
    /// <summary>
    /// Tag (nome) del Payload a cui il carrier risulta associato. null se non associato ad alcun payload.
    /// </summary>
    [JsonPropertyName("payload")]
    public string? PayloadTag { get => Name; set => Name = validateString<Carrier>(value, 64); }
}
```

The generics in the validateString() methods are just Serilog.ForContext<TLogContext>() generic type parameters.
validateString() is shared by many records types.

**Is there a way for me to bind the generic type to some static variable/attribute so i can easily alter all of them on every validateString<>() within each specific record class?**

like an overridable protected field in the MavApiRecordBase abstract class..?

```
protected override Type defLogCtx {get; set;} = typeof(Carrier);  
//then either
validateString<defLogCtx>(..) //whithin Carrier //has the pro of faster edit
//or removing the generic altogheter.
```

validateString() for reference:

```
public static string validateString<TLogContext>(string? str, int maxLen) {
    if (str is null)
        Log.ForContext<TLogContext>().Error("rogue null reference. used empty string instead.");
    else if (str.Length > maxLen)
        Log.ForContext<TLogContext>().Warning("max string length is {l}. Got {val}.", maxLen, str);

    return str.Truncate(maxLen) ?? "";
}
```

p.s. find-replace is a pain for me in VisualStudio right now, and i'm also wondering if something like this is at all possible (i just began using C#)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass the `Type` object to the non-generic `ForContext`.

```cs
public static string validateString(Type logContextType, string? str, int maxLen)
{
    if (str is null)
        Log.ForContext(logContextType).Error("rogue null reference. used empty string instead.");
    else if (str.Length > maxLen)
        Log.ForContext(logContextType).Warning("max string length is {l}. Got {val}.", maxLen, str);

    return str.Truncate(maxLen) ?? "";
}
```

In `MavApiRecordBase` you can add

```cs
protected Type DefLogCtx { get; set; }
```

and in its constructor add

```cs
DefLogCtx = this.GetType();
```

Comment: oh, i didn't notice serilog had that overload.  
That will do it just fine!  
If that wasn't the case is there also a syntax like validateString<typeof(something)>(..)?

Comment: No you would need reflection and `MakeGenericMethod` for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can move the generic type parameter from the validate method to the `MavApiRecordBase` class

```cs
public abstract MavApiRecordBase<TLogContext>
{
    public static string validateString(string? str, int maxLen)
    {
        ...
        Log.ForContext<TLogContext>().Error("message");
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Then declare the records like this

```cs
internal record Carrier : MavApiRecordBase<Carrier>
{
    public string Name { get => Name; set => Name = validateString(value, 64); }
    ...
}
```